# How to handle absolute value in Gurobi constraints

Tags: gurobi

I want to handle absolute value in Gurobi constraints.  This is my code abc.lp. However I am not getting solution.

```
Maximize
  v0 + v1 + v2



SubjeCt To
C1: 3 v0 + v1 + v2 <=   72

C2: 2 v0 + 3 v1 + 2 v2 <= 80

C3: abs_(v0 - v1) + abs_(v1 - v2) >= 10

Integers 
v0 v1 v2
End
```

Comment: Try using a general constraint in Gurobi, https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/constraints.html.

Answer (score 2):

The `abs_` function is part of the Gurobi Python API and does not work in an LP file. (When your LP file is read, the solver interprets your `C3` constraint as a linear constraint with four variables with names `abs_(v0`, `v1)`, `abs_(v1`, and `v2)`.)

Also, note that absolute value constraints can only take the form `var1 = abs_(var2)`. So you will have to define some auxiliary variables to model the constraint above.

In the Python API, you could model the constraint `C3` as follows:

```
a = model.addVars(4, name="a")   # auxiliary variables
model.addConstr(a[0] == v0 - v1)
model.addConstr(a[1] == v1 - v2)
model.addConstr(a[2] == abs_(a[0]))
model.addConstr(a[3] == abs_(a[1]))

model.addConstr(a[2] + a[3] >= 10)
```

In the LP file, you can see the absolute value constraint in the General Constraints section:

```
General Constraints
 GC0: a[2] = ABS ( a[0] )
 GC1: a[3] = ABS ( a[1] )
```